# generated signed apk according to the documentation of react-native but it does not appear on my device

Tags: android, react-native, apk, expo

I've developed my first RN application and generated the apk as the react-native's documentation says and everything is fine, it does not show me any error, but when I install the apk in an emulator or on my smartphone the application does not appear anywhere, if I get into all applications to uninstall my application previously installed it is there but when I'm going to use it does not appear any icon or whatever. Any idea why I can not see my app? I used *detach* (Expo SDK)

Comment: It seems that your app lacks a launcher activity.

Comment: @PavelB. It does have a launcher in the manifest `<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

        <data android:scheme="ccraftfinance"/>

        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
      </intent-filter>`